# Regex to bulk replace attributes[x] with getAttribute in HTML files

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, notepad++

In a boatload of HTML pages, I need to replace all strings like this:

```
language[0].attributes[24].value;
```

with this:

```
language[0].getAttribute("attr"+24);
```

where '24' can be any number.

I thought I could use Notepad++'s Find and Replace with regular expressions to do this, but have had no luck so far after much trial and error.  I don't want to have to do this manually.

(This is because, when I upgraded to IE10, all the text on the webpages I support went out of whack. It seems that by definition XML attributes can be in any order, and that newer versions of IE reorder them. I now need to reference the attributes by name instead of index.)

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find the following regular expression:

```
\.attributes\[(\d+)\]\.value
```

And replace it with

```
.getAttribute("attr"+\1)
```

http://regexr.com?33b0j  <-- See it in action!

Answer (score 0):

You should use some wildcard replace tools in some text editor. I personally use VS. MS-Office programs such as word has that possibility too.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `\.attribute\[(\d+)\]\.value;`
Replace with: `.getAttribute\("attr" + \1\);`

(I had to escape the brackets in the replace value for my version of Notepad++ to)

Comment: You don't have to escape the brackets because of Notepad++, it's because brackets delineate character sets in Regular Expressions.

Comment: I'm talking about the **replace** value not the **find** value

Comment: Okay.  Got confused because you don't have any brackets in your replace value, and thought you mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with notepad++

```
language\[0\].attributes\[\s*(\d+)\s*\].value;
```

replaced with

```
language[0].getAttribute\("attr"+\1\);
```